# a simple sum of columns in a 2D list

Tags: python

```
import random

ROWS = 3
COLS = 3

def main():

    values = [[0,0,0], [0,0,0], [0,0,0]]
    for r in range(ROWS):
        for c in range(COLS):
            values[r][c] = random.randint(1, 4)
    print('List:')
    print(values)
    print(sum(values[0]))
    print(sum(values[1]))
    print(sum(values[2]))

main()
```

This is the code that I have written and what I would like to do is display the the individual totals for each column. For example, the final result would look like:

```
Total of column 0 is 7

Total of column 1 is 6



Total of column 2 is 7
```

Answer (score 1):

Builtin python lists are not very ideal for working with matrix-like data.  I would highly suggest using numpy:

```
import numpy as np

l = np.array(values)
l.sum(axis=1)
```

However, if you really need to use python lists, one strategy is just to reduce your outer list with your desired output.

```
reducer = lambda x, y : [x[i] + y[i] for i in range(len(x)]
reduce(reducer, values)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply reverse the order of ROWS and COLS in another pair of nested loops:

```
import random

ROWS = 3
COLS = 3

values = list()

for r in range(ROWS):
    values.append(list())
    for c in range(COLS):
        values[r].append(random.randint(1, 4))

print('List:', values, sep="\n")

for c in range(COLS):
    sum = 0
    for r in range(ROWS):
        sum += values[r][c]
    print("Total of column {} is {}".format(c, sum))
```

Produces:

```
List:
[[3, 2, 4], [4, 3, 4], [4, 2, 3]]


Total of column 0 is 11
Total of column 1 is 7
Total of column 2 is 11
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
import random
ROWS=3
COLS=3

def main():
    values = []
    for i in range(ROWS):
        list1=[]
        for j in range(COLS):
            val =random.randint(1,4)
            list1.append(val)
        values.append(list1)
    print (values)

    for col in range(COLS):

        sum = 0
        for row in range(ROWS):
            sum += values[row][col]
        print("Total of column "+str(col)+" is " +str(sum))
main()

[[4, 1, 2], [2, 3, 4], [3, 3, 1]]
Total of column 0 is 9
Total of column 1 is 7
Total of column 2 is 7
```

Answer (score -1):

I ended up using something which now seems quite simple:

thank you for your responses

```
values = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
for r in range(ROWS):
    for c in range(COLS):
        values[r][c] = random.randint(1, 4)
print('List:')
print(values)
print('Total of row 0 is', sum(values[0]))
print('Total of row 1 is', sum(values[1]))
print('Total of row 2 is', sum(values[2]))
valuescolumn1 = [row[0] for row in values]
print('Total of column 0 is', sum(valuescolumn1))
valuescolumn2 = [row[1] for row in values]
print('Total of column 1 is', sum(valuescolumn2))
valuescolumn3 = [row[1] for row in values]
print('Total of column 2 is', sum(valuescolumn3))
```